# how to list all files in a directory unix using scp (exec channel) and java

Tags: java, unix, sftp, scp

I am trying to get list of files in a unix directory, using below code

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
           Session  session = jsch.getSession("user", "ip",port);
           session.setPassword("pwd");
           java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();

           config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

           session.setConfig(config);
           session.connect();

           String remotedir = "/home/user/myDir";
           Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
           ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("cd " + remotedir + " && ls");
           channel.connect();
           channel.run();
```

I have written code till here , but dont know further steps to get the list of files from the directory.

Comment: its not duplicate , I am using a different channel ("exec"), the question which you are referring is using sftp channel

Comment: Using SFTP would be much simpler than using a plain exec channel. If you really can't use SFTP for some reason, you should explicitly say so in your question. And since your question includes code for running "ls" on the remote system, you should be more clear about what spcific problem you're having.

Comment: and if the issue is reading from the channel the output, look for "jsch output" (without quotes) and you'll find a lot of question about that

Comment: channelExec.setCommand("ls -t > " + "" + fileName); 
After using this command ,i am able to get of list of filenames and store them in a file.